# How to refresh VF page after creating or editing the record using sforce.one?

Tags: apex, visualforce, sforce

I'm new to salesforce, I have created a VF page for creating and editing a record using sforce.one

Below is my syntax:

```js
 if ( typeof (id) == 'string' && taskassignfieldresp.keyPrefix == id.substring(0,3)) {
         sforce.one.editRecord(id);
     } else {
         sforce.one.createRecord("dftlytime__TT_Task_Assignment__c");
     }
     sforce.one.back(true);
```

I'm using sforce.one.back(true) for refreshing the VF page after saving a record but it is not working.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: No, I'm awaiting if someone here can help me fixing this.